# How to add additional event handlers to a jquery-ui datepicker instance?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got a datepicker with an onSelect event handler. Later in my program, I want to add other onSelect handlers. Problem is, they wipe out the first one. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sprugman/ddrQJ/).)

How can I add additional handlers without doing that?

Comment: Seems this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2241725/1030169

Comment: I thought it would be, but didn't find it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain your desired calls in an array;

```
var firstHandler = function(dateText, inst) {
    console.log('Original Handler', dateText, inst);
};

var secondHandler = function(dateText, inst) {
    console.log('Second Handler', dateText, inst);
};

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        var sinks = $(this).data("mySelects");
        for (var i = 0; i < sinks.length; i++)
            sinks[i].apply(this, arguments);
    }
}).data("mySelects", [firstHandler]);

$('#addBtn').click(function(event) {
    $('#datepicker').data('mySelects').push(secondHandler);
    $('#datepicker').data('mySelects').push(nthHandler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had just finished coding that when I saw the comment above. I think the linked solution is a little more elegant. Update: actually, your version is more elegant than mine. Hmm...

Comment: This solution works fine in several situations (instead the linked solution doesn't work if, in the first handler, there is a variable that comes from out the context of the first handler ). Where can i find documentation that explains me the solution? 
I cannot understand, for example, arguments variable.

Comment: `.apply(this,arguments)` calls the function in `sinks[]` making sure that `this` is correct in the handler. It also passes the `arguments` object to pass on all the arguments that `onSelect` originally received (`dateText` & `inst`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments`